# Visual Studio 2010 - cannot open database project (null reference)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, dbproj

I'm recently faced with problem that my VS2010 cannot open the database project. It's ends with:

```
<path>.dbproj : error  : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It happen with existing projects and new ones as well. I tried to repair VS 2010 together with SP1 but without success. I also tried to change instance of SQL Server in Tools->Database Tools->Data Connections

Recently I've installed VS2008 and I guess this had change something. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved that issue :) After I run repair on my default instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 it started to work again.